# Retrieving the text between the <div> with VBA

Tags: html, json, vba

I am trying to get a text string from inside a div on a webpage, but I can't seem to figure out how it is stored in the element.

```
Set eleval = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("outputValue")(0)
Debug.Print (eleval.innerText)
```

I have tried this and variations thereof, but my string just reads as "".

I mainly need help on how is this type of data is referenced in VBA.

```html
<div class="outputValue">"text data that I want"</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the page in question, I cannot give a link since it requires a company login to reach.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `.querySelector` method, make sure page if fully loaded before attempting.
Example delays can be added with `Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(h,m,s)`

```
Set eleval = objIE.Document.querySelector("div[class="outputValue"]")
Debug.Print eleval.innerText
```

If it is the first of its className on the page you could also use:

```
Set eleval = objIE.Document.querySelector(".outputValue")
```

If there is more than one and it is at a later index you can use

```
Set eleval = objIE.Document.querySelectorAll(".outputValue")
```

And then access items from the nodeList returned with

```
Debug.Print eleval.Item(0).innerText 'or replace 0 with the appropriate index.
```

Comment: Its giving me a type mismatch error on
'Set eleval = objIE.Document.querySelector(".outputValue")'

Comment: Is eleval declared as Dim eleval As Object ?

Comment: It is now, I had commented it out be mistake, but now it says "Object Required" error

Comment: Wait, it works now, it turns out the subform on the page wasn't fully loaded, and my readystate checker couldn't check that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim elaval as Variant
elaval = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("div")(X).innerText)
msgbox elaval
```

Where X is the instance of your class `div`